# Magento 2: Difference between Model and Factory

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, When to use **Factory** and **Model**?

What is the difference between them?

Can we use our Custom Module's model as Factory?

Answer (score 20):

A **Factory** creates a **Model**. It's a design pattern (separate from Magento 2).

Typically, when you need to create a new instance of your class/entity, you would want a factory to create that. So instead of:

```
$product = new Product();
```

You would do:

```
$product = $productFactory->create();
```

Having a factory instead of using the `new`-keyword has multiple benefits. For example:

- It allows for dependency injection when it comes to creating new instances (which is great for unit testing for example).
- It provides a hook into the constructing-process of your instances.
- It's more SOLID.

But you don't want to manually create all those factories by yourself (because it's boring and repeating most of the times). That's why Magento 2 uses code generation to create these factory classes for you. Just add `Factory` after the class name in your `use`-statement or constructor:

```
use Vendor\Module\Model\ExampleFactory;
```

or:

```
public function __construct(
    Vendor\Module\Model\ExampleFactory $exampleFactory
) {
    $this->exampleFactory = $exampleFactory;
}
```

Don't worry about warnings that the class does not exist by your IDE; Magento will create them for you. After a reload the class will be generated (in the `var/generation` (2.1) or `generated` (2.2) folder).

The only time when you want to create your own factory is if you want to apply some custom logic upon instantiating your object. But often that's not required.